# How to change d3 tickmark lines to circles

Tags: d3.js

How do I create a tickmark like this in D3 axis?

--o---o---o---o---o

instead of the default 
---|---|---|

I searched the D3 examples, but could not see any sample of changing the tickmark from lines to circles..

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't supported out of the box. You can however quite easily select the tick groups, append circles and delete the tick lines using something like the following code.

```
var ticks = axis.selectAll(".tick");
ticks.each(function() { d3.select(this).append("circle").attr("r", 3); });
ticks.selectAll("line").remove();
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5fUnV/).

Comment: Thanx.. Exactly what I needed..Want to upvote, but dont have enough reputation ;-(

Comment: Just one more clarification.. In the JS Fiddle example, the line tickmarks are still visible for the first and last ticks..How is it happening even though  the lines are removed ?

Comment: These are actually part of the `path` that also forms the axis line. Removing those would be trickier -- you would have to either modify the path or remove and redraw.

Comment: Ok..Will look into that.. Right now I just increased the circle radius:-)

Comment: Try ```var axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(scale).tickSize(0).tickPadding(9);``` to get an axis with no visible ticks, even at the ends.  The padding ensures labels still end up at the same position relative to the axis.  You'll still need the code Lars cited to get your circles.